# Generic as null in int,decimal,Datetime types

Tags: c#

I have this method:

```
  public static DiffModule<T> AddValue<T>(T Source, T Destination)
    {
        DiffModule<T> module = new DiffModule<T>();
        module.Source = Source;
        module.Desctination = Destination;

        var type = typeof(T);
       
        
            //Check nullable
            if(Source==null && Destination == null)
            {
                module.Result = CompareResult.Equal;
                return module;
            }
            if (Source == null)
            {
                module.Result = CompareResult.NotExistInSource;
                return module;
            }
            if (Destination == null)
            {
                module.Result = CompareResult.NotExistInDestination;
                return module;
            }
       

        
        module.Result = (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Source, Destination)) ? CompareResult.Equal : CompareResult.NotEqual;

        return module;
    }

public enum CompareResult
{
    Undefined,
    Equal,
    NotEqual,
    NotExistInSource,
    NotExistInDestination
}
```

if I Do

```
 var m1 = DiffModule<string>("Hi there",null);
```

that will return me NotExistInDestination enum result, but if i'd try

```
 var m2 = DiffModule<int>(2,null) <-- that of course is an error
```

how can I "make" the int,double,decimal,datetime types to pass to AddValue method as nullable ?
do consider that the data can be deliver from VO which is fixed with value type

ex: `public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}` and can't be `public DateTime? {get;set;}`

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the question, though... `AddValue<int?>(2, null);` or `AddValue(2, (int?)null);` ?

Comment: tried  DiffModule<double?>.AddValue(4, null) 
null throw error can't convert <null> to double - tried also with (double?)null - didn't work

Comment: As a tangential solution to the problem, you can make generic parameters nullable ([example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r1fOqs)), provided you know that the type is non-nullable.

Comment: Part of the issue in your code is that your equality comparison logic lives _outside_ of the class (i.e. `DiffModule<T>`) which houses the stored generic values. If this logic were encapsulated within `DiffModule<T>`, you would be able to account for all nullable vs non-nullable cases, while also providing a reusable interface to outside consumers.

Comment: _"that of course is an error"_ You've never shown the class definition of `DiffModule<>` nor the actual error you get, so it's impossible to judge. We can _guess_ at what your constructor definition might be, but it's better to see the actual code than guess what it might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *value types* can't be `null`, end of story. When you supply `null` and a *value type* to a single generic parameter the compiler (via *static analysis*) correctly informs you that something is wrong.

> cannot convert from <null> to <Type>

Because, it's not convertible!, there is no implicit conversion...

There is also no way you can add a *constraint* or modify the signature for it to infer a *nullable* (in this situation) or *anti-lift* (just made that up) a *value type* and reference types..

All you can to is *explicitly* tell the compiler what you intend via the type parameter, or casting `null` to its *nullable* counterpart:

```
AddValue<int?>(2, null); 

// or

AddValue(2, (int?)null);
```

Comment: Tried this - had complier errors - T - can't be null when it's property of a class

Comment: @Izikon works for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/MruvKQ

Comment: works!. the problem was with the property - which i need to bypass...

Answer (score 0):

In C# a general T can't be nullable, you should use **"T?"** The question mark indicates a nullable value that of course can be nullable end you can null check the value.
Also basically in C# primitive types can't be nullable but from C# 2 it can be possible using the question mark notation like **int? bool? float?**